# \diamond not available with Libertinus Math and LuaLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, symbols, luatex, libertinus

The folling MWE produces no diamond symbol when compiled with LuaLaTeX. The log file contains the message

```
Missing character: There is no ⋄ (U+22C4) in font [LibertinusMath-Regular.otf]
:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;;!
```

The pdfLaTeX version of the font does not have this problem (or at least compiling the MWE with pdfLaTeX gives the desired output.) Does the font really not contain the `\diamond` symbol? How can I work around this?

```latex
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}

\verb|\diamond|: \(\diamond\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you use your example with pdflatex `\diamond` is from cmsy not from libertinus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrow it from another font. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertinus}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[range=\smwhtdiamond]
\setmathfont{LibertinusMath-Regular.otf}[range=]

\begin{document}

\verb|\diamond|: \(x \diamond y\)

\end{document}
```

In `unicode-math-table.tex` you see that U+22C4 is `\smwhtdiamond` and it's a `\mathbin`; `\diamond` is an alias.

[image]

Next, ask the maintainers of Libertinus Math to add the glyph.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\begin{document}
    
    \verb|\diamond|: \(\diamondsuit\)
    
    $\vardiamondsuit$
    
\setmathfont{XITS}  
    $\diamondcdot$
    
    $\mdwhtdiamond$
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are some more diamond commands ...